# Setting Content-Security-Policy header in Angular 6 application

Tags: angular, express

I'm reading an (excellent) book, "Pro Angular 6" from Adam Freeman and I was able to replicate his pretty complex examples in dev-mode without problems. However, a relatively short chapter "SportsStore: Progressive Features and Deployment" is driving me nuts.

Honestly, there's not much in it. You just have to run the application in production mode. The Node/Express server keeps sending the response header that, I think, prevents the app from rendering in the browser. The error I get is:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico (“default-src”).
```

And if you look at the response headers, you see that something is wrong:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
```

This (I think) is the root cause of my problem. This kind of policy prevents the app from being rendered in the browser.

I tried to add a different setting (like 'self' instead of 'none') in various places including server.js. You can check two tries of mine in the file (one of them is using 'helmet' package which should be the right tool for this purpose:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const history = require("connect-history-api-fallback");
const jsonServer = require("json-server");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const auth = require("./authMiddleware");
const router = jsonServer.router("serverdata.json");
const enableHttps = false;
const ssloptions = {}
const helmet = require(`helmet`)

if (enableHttps) {
    ssloptions.cert =  fs.readFileSync("./ssl/localhost.crt");
    ssloptions.key = fs.readFileSync("./ssl/localhost.key");
}
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(auth);
app.use("/api", router);
app.use(history());
app.use("/", express.static("./dist/SportsStore"));

// TRY 1
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
  directives: {
    defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
    styleSrc: ["'self'", 'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com']
  }
}))

// TRY 2
// custom header
app.all("/*", function(req, res, next) {
   res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'none'");
   next();
});

app.listen(8080,
    () => console.log("HTTP Server running on port 8080"));
if (enableHttps) {
    https.createServer(ssloptions, app).listen(8443,
        () => console.log("HTTPS Server running on port 8443"));
} else {
    console.log("HTTPS disabled")
}
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "sport-store",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "json": "json-server data.js -p 3500 -m authMiddleware.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.8.9",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^6.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "helmet": "^3.21.2",
    "helmet-csp": "^2.9.4",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "json-server": "^0.12.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

I compile the code with:

```
ng build --prod
```

and run the app with:

```
node server.js
```

In both cases I don't get a single warning. I have run out of ideas so any help will be highly appreciated.